# Caddy file server browse not working when I root a specific directory

Tags: caddy, fileserver, caddyfile

Here is my `Caddyfile`:

```
aruiplex.com {
        encode gzip
        file_server /files/* {
                root /files
                browse
        }
        reverse_proxy /api/* localhost:7022
        file_server {
                root /srv
        }
}
```

Here is my plan:

1. When request URL is `aruiplex.com`, Caddy can show me the `index.html` in `/srv` directory.
2. When request URL is `aruiplex.com/files`, Caddy can show me the file list in the `/files` directory in docker container.
3. When request URL is `aruiplex.com/api`, Caddy can pass this request to `localhost:7022`.

But when I request `aruiplex.com/files` file server is not working, it gives me a 404. And I have check this directory in docker container, there have some files.

Here is my file tree at `/` in docker container:

```
/
    /home
    /etc
    /...
    /files
        /aaa.txt
        /bbb.txt
    /srv
        /index.html
```

Version: Caddy 2.4.6 in Docker.

P.S.: If you see the post on the [caddy.community](https://caddy.community/t/file-server-root-and-browse-not-work/15342), it also me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Deploying and serving different contents of the project

Serve the website, API, and content of the folder with the `handle` and `handle_path` directives to serve

Here is the sample project I created for the same usercase

```
├── Caddyfile
├── app
│   └── index.html
├── docker-compose.yml
├── files
│   ├── bye.txt
│   └── hello.txt
└── logs
    └── access.log
```

Caddyfile, replace `8080` with your domain `example.com`

```
:8080 {
    handle /api* {
        reverse_proxy localhost:7022
    }
    handle_path /files* {
        root * /files
        file_server browse
    }
    handle {
        root * /srv
        file_server browse
    }
}

:7022 {
    respond "Hey! I AM API" 
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  caddy:
    restart: always
    image: caddy:2.4.6
    container_name: caddy
    ports:
      - 8080:8080 # Configure Caddyfile with port opened
    volumes:
      - ./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
      - ./app:/srv
      - ./files:/files
      - ./logs:/var/log
volumes:
  caddy_data: 
  caddy_config:
```

Comment: Ah thank you, first time I tried caddy and I've been banging my head trying to figure out why the `file_server` wouldn't work. `handle` worked brilliantly, very similar to nginx `location` blocks.